# Why aren't mortar domain decomposition techniques used as much as schwarts type DD?

Tags: finite-element, domain-decomposition

Schwartz type domain decomposition techniques require a transmission condition which can be hard to come by. Mortar type techniques enforce continuity with a Lagrange multiplier across domains. Are there limitations to this approach?

Comment: We don't know how to precondition the saddle point problem that results from the Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: [FETI-DP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FETI-DP) uses Lagrange multipliers to enforce continuity across domains and is (as far as I know) pretty popular. I always thought mortar methods meant that you might not have conforming meshes across the interface. So I wonder if you just have a terminology problem and need to be searching for slightly different things.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth There's a chapter on preconditioning saddle-point problems in the book by Toselli and Widlund.

Comment: @lightxbulb Right. People have spent a lot of thought on the matter, but just haven't come up with things that work as well as multigrid on a non-DD global problem distributed across different processors.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth The best thing I have done in practice is DD + full multigrid (though in a simpler fdm setting with just schwarz DD used as a smoother). DD helped mainly with reducing the memory access overhead since I could work with local memory longer on a GPU core rather than accessing global memory often - it was several times faster than simple multigrid (asymptotically they were equivalent though). I am definitely not the best implementation person around, but dismissing DD outright sounds off to me considering the experience I have had with it.

Comment: @lightxbulb My impression is that DD is a fine strategy if you want to partition into 100 subdomains, but that it just does not work very well with 10,000 or 100,000. I take your point of experience, that's the kind of thing I enjoy learning about.